# How to remove "Create new view" from view dropdown to the list

Tags: list, list-view, dropdown

Is that possible to remove the "Create new view" option from the view dropdown?

Comment: Could you specify, where exactly the mentioned "Create new view" item is located? Do you mean ribbon, and if yes, then in what tab - "Browse" or "List" or "Library"?

Comment: To all the list and library. I have to hide in ribbon, in view drop down and the library setting. What i mean is if some x group user login to portal they should not have access to create/ modify/ delete view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hiding these links from that many locations actually causes a lot of pain and anyway is not secure. An advanced user could just enter the direct link to the view creation page, and all your efforts would be to no purpose.

Thus, this is a permissions question, and all you need is just to set appropriate permissions to your portal users.

To achieve this, click "Site Actions" => "Site permissions", locate button "Permissions levels" on the ribbon, and then create a new permission level (or modify existent one).

When creating the new permission level, assure that the settings "Manage Lists" and "Manage Personal Views" are unchecked:

[image]
[image]

After this, create a SharePoint users group, configure it to use this new permission level and include all the users you need to this group.

Comment: First thing i am not able to set this through UI. Second thing what ever u r telling i am achived this through code also. there i am getting some permission issue because ia m not able to remove the manage list permission from full control. Any way thanks for ur idea to get this idea and write the code i spent two days.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can able to find the example

http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2016/06/how-to-restrict-users-for-creating.html